# MVVM Itemsouce button command and calling another view

Tags: c#, mvvm, itemsource

'PLease help'. I need to call another view from view model when edit button pressed. showdailog() i can not use anymore. I am calling another child view from this view. please help

> Edit-->
>                                           
>                                       Delete</Button>
>                                   </Border>
>                                   </Border>
>                                   </Border>
>                                   </Border>
>                                   </Border>
>                                   </Border>
>                                   </Border>-->

```
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
        </StackPanel>    
    </ScrollViewer>

    <Button Command ="{Binding SubmitCommand}" Name="Submit" Content="Search" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="349,45,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    <Button Command ="{Binding CloseCommand}" Name="Close" Content="Close" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="535,379,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    <Button Command ="{Binding ReLoadCommand}" Name="Reload" Content="ReLoad" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="535,45,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    <Button Command ="{Binding ClearCommand}" Name="Clear" Content="CLear" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="443,45,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    <Label x:Name="label" Content="Enter First Name or Last Name for Search" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="84,18,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedYear}" Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
              Margin="10,379,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectedItem="{Binding Item}">
        <!--SelectedItem="{Binding Item} -->
    </ComboBox>



</Grid>
```

ViewModel:

```
    private ICommand _editRowData;

    public ICommand EditRowData
    {
        get { return _editRowData ?? (_editRowData = new CommandHandler(() => RowDataAction(), _canExecute)); }
    }


   private SecondWindowViewModel childView;
    public void RowDataAction()
    {
        childView = new SecondWindowViewModel();
        //MessageBox.Show("Edit Button Pressed");
        SecondWindow view = new SecondWindow()
        {
            DataContext = childView

        };

        childView.Labelcontent = "kala";

        view.ShowDailog();

        //view.ShowDailog() is giving me error. Please explain and provide me solve.
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say you need to "call second window"? If you want to display it then call `Show()`. Also you've tagged this as MVVM but it isn't...you never create UI elements directly in a MVVM application.

Comment: var viewModel = new SecondWindowViewModel();
            var view = new SecondWindow();
            view.DataContext = viewModel;
            view.Show();         

         view.show is not working. What I m doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the button binding to this:

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.EditRowData, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ItemsControl}}" ... etc
```

Comment: childView = new SecondWindowViewModel();
            //MessageBox.Show("Edit Button Pressed");
            SecondWindow view = new SecondWindow()
            {
                DataContext = childView
            };

            childView.Labelcontent = "kala";

            view.ShowDialog();                        

Why showdailog() asking me to create another method. Please help.